# Good basic windows XP laptop loadout?

Tags: windows, laptop

At the moment I am setting up an old windows laptop to give to my mother (to replace an ancient desktop). It's been a few years since I seriously used windows, so I am not very knowledgeable about the current best practices. I have installed Avira anti-virus as it is what I use on Windows virtual machines, but suggestions for good free AV would also be welcome.

1. What software would be considered indispensable on a Windows XP machine?
2. Any recommendations for useful apps that might help a beginner get more out of the machine?
3. Any settings that I should change before handing the machine over?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is a good question, but not for this website. We generally don't do software recommendations here, and your question will invite a lot of discussion, where on SuperUser, we want questions that can be definitively answered. I'm aware of no sites that will give you generally "indispensable" or "useful" software on WinXP without a purpose in mind. There is a site for recommendations, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, but they have similar requirements - single-purpose questions with definitive answers. I'm sorry I can't be more help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you asked her what she actually wants to do with it?

Personally I'd be inclined to *remove* stuff more than *add* it.

I'd consider:

- A modern browser, configured to block popups
- Office tools if she wants them
- Some games (solitaire etc) if she wants them
- Anti-virus, as you've mentioned

I'd say the way to help a beginner get more out of the machine would be not to overwhelm them. Talking to your mother will probably get you more useful information than talking to us :)

Whether you want to go into "here's an admin account to use when you have to, here's a non-admin account to use for the rest of the time" will depend on whether you think she will be able to take it all in.

Comment: Great points! I just gave my mom a self-refurbished desktop. Went through the same points. This resonates.

Comment: Hi Jon, I already asked and she gave me carte blanche to set it up: she considers herself a beginner and wants to use the machine to learn more about computers. The problem is I don't know that much about windows to set it up for a beginner!

Comment: Make sure you have some remote desktop software installed, to fix remotelly any problems that apear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Microsoft Office, anti-virus software, spyware/malware/adware removal tools
2. Outlook completely installed and configured
3. Make a user account that is not an administrator for her to use.